# Is WHICH referring to A, B or something else in "A is ... B ... and from which"?

Tags: meaning

A Cambridge english [vocabulary](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/Images/84669-pet-vocabulary-list.pdf) says

> The Cambridge Learner Corpus is a collection of over 44 million words of English, based upon evidence of language use by learners from all over the world and from `which` the English Vocabulary Profile has developed. The English Vocabulary Profile shows the most common words and phrases that learners of English need to know in British or American English. The meaning of each word or phrase in the wordlists has been assigned a level between A1 and B2 on the CEFR.

Is WHICH referring to "The Cambridge Learner Corpus", "evidence of language" or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context you would have to assume that the "English Vocabulary Profile" was developed from the "Cambridge Learner Corpus".  Any other interpretation doesn't make sense.

In reading you must be thinking about the meanings of words and not only the grammatical connections between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, in a complex sentence, WHICH is NOT necessarily referring to the 
nearest noun/pronoun, right?

Comment: not always. ...